# Javascript add delay in loop by condition

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
var count = 1;

for (var key in result.data) {
    if (count == 10) {
        // I want to delay 1 second here
    }

    var value = result.data[key];
    generate(key, value);
    count++;
}
```

As you see , I iterate throught `result.data` , and added `count` to determine when to add delay.
I just want to add 1 second delay inside this loop when `count == 10` as I shown .

Comment: try  `wait (1000);` or `await delay(1000);`

Comment: use setTimeout() like setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000); in your if

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Answer (score 2):

You can use async/await to pause for a sec. Like this.

```
(async () => {

    let count = 1;

    const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5];

    for (let key in array) {

        if (count === 10) {

            await new Promise((resolve) => {

                console.log('Paused for 1 sec');

                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('Continued');
                    resolve();
                }, 1000);
            });
        }

        console.log(key);

        count++;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you:

```
function delay(functionToDelay, ms) {
return function() {
  var savedThis = this;
  var savedArguments = arguments;

  setTimeout(function() {
    functionToDelay.apply(savedThis, savedArguments);
  }, ms);
  };
}
```

First argument - function you want to delay.
Second - milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you want to call the `generate` function after 1 second when the `count` is 10

You can use `setTimeout` like this:

```js
var result = {
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
}

var count = 1;

for (let key in result.data) {
    if (count == 10) {
        setTimeout(() => generate(key, result.data[key]), 1000)
    } else {
        generate(key, result.data[key])
    }

    count++;
}

function generate(key, value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need is [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Your code will be something like this:

```
var count = 1;

for (var key in result.data) {
    if (count == 10) {
        // I want to delay 1 second here
        setTimeout(function(){ alert("1 second delay!"); }, 1000);
    }

    var value = result.data[key];
    generate(key, value);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to take the `alert()`

Comment: But this does not cause to wait loop

Answer (score -1):

Below you can find usable example for it.

**PS: Edit**

```
for (var key in result.data) {
    if (count == 10) {
        // I want to delay 1 second here
        setTimeout(generate.bind(key, result.data[key]), 1000);
    }
    else
        generate(key, result.data[key])
    count++;
}
```